# How to change previous date log file permision to read only in Log4Net?

Tags: asp.net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using Log4Net in my window application, Now i want to change the permission of my all previous date logs to read only automatically and only current date log file will remain same or not changed. How can i do this using Log4Net or is it possible in any other plugin like Elmah ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. You can invest to extend the file appender you are using to make the file ReadOnly when it is rolled. You can see the find the [log4net source code here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/source-repository.html). Look for the appenders and then extend/ or copy that appender in you project. Make the changes and then use your own appender in the configuration.

Comment: Thanks @peter and one more question is that is it possible to do this by using  Elmah or Enterprise Liabrary or any other error logging  methodology?

Comment: Maybe its a better idea to log to a db and give the user only insert rights.